# What's the difference between a "stopped" and an "exited" container?

Tags: docker, state

Is there a functional difference here?  I can `docker start` either one to make it go again.  What's the difference?

Answer (score 3):

It is quite different.

A stopped container can be restarted, unlike an exited container.

Suppose you have a stopped container, which has an id of 21F123 (that is enough to identify it).

`docker start 21F123`

may succeed.

If your container exits, you can try to launch it again, but it will have a new, different pid in

`docker ps`

Comment: How does one stop a container or exit a container?

Comment: See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached-vs-foreground and in particluar the `Exit Status` on that page, and the various restart policies

Comment: Most probably the behavior has been changed as I see the same container id from `docker ps` after exited container has been started with `docker start`. Using Docker version 19.03.5.